# skip a sheet in excel workbook using openxml(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

iterating through all sheets in workbook using openxml(C#) but  want to skip a specific sheet based on its name.Please suggest how it can be done.

Comment: condition for sheet name in your loop: if (sheet.Name != "not me")

Comment: what did you try? anything? show the code, explain what issue you specifically have

Comment: i have a task to compare 2 excel sheets.Here i am taking data into a datatable. My all sheets have values starting from row 2 (A2)so i have set a condition according to that,except 1 sheet which is the first sheet. this sheet is not matching the condition ==> if (row.RowIndex.Value == 2)

Answer (score 0):

> The sheet names are stored in the WorkbookPart in a Sheets element
>   which has children of element Sheet which corresponds to each
>   worksheet in the Excel file.

See the answer given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504285/how-to-retrieve-tab-names-from-excel-sheet-using-openxml). 
Make your own loop and skip the sheet according to its name.