# How to get a Sheet by name in Open XML SDK for Excel

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I am testing the possible replacement of the EPPlus library in an ASP.Net MVC application written in C# with the Open XML SDK library because of a bug in EPPlus we can't squash with Macro Enabled Spreadsheets. One think I liked about EPPlus was that the I could use this:

```
public ExcelWorksheet this[string Name] { get; }
```

to get the worksheet by name. Looking at the definition of the Sheets class in Open XML SDK, there is not a similar construct.

I already have the tab name. I need to get the associated worksheet so I can edit it without looping through all of the sheets each time I need the sheet.

Everything I found has been the opposite, getting the name of a Sheet object. Is there a way to get the Sheet by the tab text in Open XML SDK? OR should I download the source and add this feature to the class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve Tab names from excel sheet using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504285/how-to-retrieve-tab-names-from-excel-sheet-using-openxml)

Comment: No, I'm trying to do the opposite of that. I need the sheet to edit based upon the tab name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below method to get WorkSheet with sheetName.

```
public static Worksheet GetworksheetBySheetName(string sheetName)
 {
   using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Sheet7.xlsx", true))
   {
     var workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
                string relationshipId = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.Equals(sheetName))?.Id;

     var worksheet = ((WorksheetPart)workbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId)).Worksheet;

     return worksheet;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer, however has what I was looking for - [How to retrieve Tab names from excel sheet using OpenXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504285/how-to-retrieve-tab-names-from-excel-sheet-using-openxml). <s>I'm working on implementing the changes into my application and will post the code then.</s> I wrapped the functionality into a generic utility class based upon that answer.

Utility Class Code:

```
public static class OpenXMLUtilities
{
    public static void UpdateCell(SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet, string sheetName, DataAccess.Domain.CellType cellType, string value, uint rowIndex, string columnName)
    {
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadSheet, sheetName);

        if (worksheetPart != null)
        {
            Cell cell = GetCell(worksheetPart.Worksheet, columnName, rowIndex);

            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);

            switch (cellType)
            {
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.BidLocation:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Constant:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Email:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.General:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Industry:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Name:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.ProposalNumber:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Department:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Money:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Phone:
                    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
                    break;
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Date:
                    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Date);
                    break;
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Float:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.Integer:
                    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Number);
                    break;
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.YesNoOrBlank:
                case DataAccess.Domain.CellType.YesOrNo:
                    cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.Boolean);
                    break;
            }

            worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
        }
    }

    public static WorksheetPart GetWorksheetPartByName(SpreadsheetDocument document, string sheetName)
    {
        IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName);

        if (sheets.Count() == 0)
        {
            // The specified worksheet does not exist.
            return null;
        }

        string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);

        return worksheetPart;
    }

    private static Cell GetCell(Worksheet worksheet, string columnName, uint rowIndex)
    {
        Row row = GetRow(worksheet, rowIndex);

        if (row == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return row.Elements<Cell>().Where(c => string.Compare(c.CellReference.Value, columnName + rowIndex, true) == 0).First();
    }
    private static Row GetRow(Worksheet worksheet, uint rowIndex)
    {
        return worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>().Elements<Row>().Where(r => r.RowIndex == rowIndex).First();
    }

}
```

Comment: And that's exactly the post that was proposed as duplicate that you said "No" to...

Comment: I'm a moron without enough coffee. I freely admit that.

Answer (score 0):

find url for EPPlus sourcecode
https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus